# I have forgotten my password to my laptop, and can't access GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, password

I forgot my password to my laptop. I know the passcode in the startup that is displayed on the bottom with white stars. But, not my actual account password. I can only use it in guest mode, and that isn't great use at all.

I looked up how to reset it online and they all said to hold Shift or press it multiple times, or press esc to get to the GRUB menu to reset it. My laptop just doesn't seem to want too get to that menu. It did to begin with I'm pretty sure. When I first installed Ubuntu, I had the option to click Windows 7 or Ubuntu, but later just made Ubuntu the only OS, so that screen doesn't shop up.

I don't know what to do anymore, I really would like to be able to get back into my laptop if it's possible at all. I don't care about the materials inside of it, it didn't have much information on it anyways. Just a few games. If there is something I missed or don't know about. Please reply, I've been stuck like this for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

If you forgot your password for your Linux login, you can remove the password and set up a new one.

When Linux is booting, hit the Shift key to access the grub menu.  You have to hit it at the right time.  You also may have to hit it more than once to be sure you hit it at the right time.

Use the arrows to select the Advanced Options -> [Arrow to Enter recovery mode] -> [Arrow to Enter Drop to root shell] ->

Now, remount your drive to write access with:

```
# mount -o remount,rw /
```

Edit your /etc/passwd file and remove the "x" from the second field.  This removes the password.

You can now exit out of the shell, reboot your computer and log into your account without a password.

While in your normal access edit the /etc/passwd file again and place the "x" back in to the second field.  Now you can set your password to a new one.

Comment: I've tried accessing GRUB with Shift multiple times, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Tale a look at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1674192.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a BIOS password try removing the CMOS battery[image]